# how to save 1 frame of registered depth image?

Tags: ros, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried modifying the image view nodes image_saver and extract_image but it still gives me error `cant convert 16UC1 to BRG8`.  I want to save it in png type.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216742/how-to-save-1-frame-of-registered-depth-image?/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just use:

```
rosrun image_view image_saver image:=/camera/depth_registered/image_raw _encoding:=16UC1 _filename_format:="image%04i.png"
```

Get sure the topic is published. Maybe you need to activate registration with dynamic reconfiguration.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2015-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-09-09**:
For reference for anyone else finding this, if the encoding is `32FC1` then this works (and using 16UC1 will produce blank images)

```
rosrun image_view image_saver image:=/camera/depth_registered/image_raw _encoding:=32FC1 _filename_format:="image%04i.tif"
```

tif is needed to save as a float, png will crush it down to 8-bit.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2021-09-09**:
The specified encoding must of course match the data. When I wrote the answer 6 years ago, all sensors coded the depth with 2 bytes and thus the command above was correct for all /.../depth_registered/image_raw topcis. Unfortunately, I'm now in a completely different technological environment, but I'm a bit surprised that a sensor delivers 32FC1: In my time, only 11 to 12 (if I remember right) of the 16 bits were used, so there was still some space left.